# No comprendo la funcion callback

Tags: javascript, callback

Estoy aprendiendo la funcion callback pero no logro ejecutarla. Tengo un ejercicio y me da error.
La consigana es:

Vamos a crear tres funciones y ver cómo empezar a trabajar con callbacks.
La primera función se llamará doble. Esta recibirá un número y retornará el doble.
La segunda función se llamará triple. Esta recibirá un número y retornará el triple.
La tercera función se llamará aplicarCallback y recibirá por parámetro un numero y una función. Esta retornará el valor de aplicar dicha función al valor que recibió.

el ejercicio que hago:

```
function doble(num1){
    return (num1*2)
}
function triple (num2){
    return (num2 *3)
}
function aplicarCallback(num,doble){
    return(10,callback)
 }
```

no logro entender el concepto!

Answer (score 1):

Lo que no estás entendiendo son cómo se ejecutan las funciones. Ten en cuenta que los *callbacks* son funciones para manejar procesos asíncronos y saber cuándo estén listos. En la función `aplicarCallback`, estás devolviendo `10`. Lo que debes de hacer es ejecutar la función callback y devolver el valor que da

```
function aplicarCallback(n, f) { return f(n); }
```

Básicamente lo que estamos haciendo es definir la función `aplicarCallback` la cual recibe dos parámetros, el número y una función. Vamos a ejecutar la función y devolver lo que nos de dicha función. Ten en cuenta que en `return` tampoco necesitas paréntesis y para ejecutar una función sí son necesarios. Ejemplo:

```js
fn()
```

Puedes referenciarte de la siguiente documentación: [Funciones](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)